# jquery keep the variable, dont set it to 0 every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code rotates the image only once - 90' and then stops working. Like the `angle` is always being set to `0` every time I call it. How do I fix this? I need to keep the angle in the variable.

**FILE1.js**

```
$(function () {
  $('.rotate-receipt').on('click', function() {
    handleImage.rotateImage(0, this);
  });
});
```

**FILE2.js**

```
var handleImage = (function () {
  return {
    rotateImage: function (angle, element) {
      var index = $(element).data('button-index');
      angle = (angle + 90)%360;
      var className = 'rotate' + angle;
      $('#receipt-image-'+index).removeClass().addClass(className);
    }
  };
}());
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle, or at least show your html?

Comment: its in rails so hard to show

Comment: Don't replace a question after it is answered. SO is a Q&A site; leave your Q&A here to help others.  If necessary, I think you can delete your own question instead of replacing it with rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

You must capture the variable you wish to "remember".

File 1:

```
$(function () {
  $('.rotate-receipt').on('click', rotateImage(0, $('.rotate-receipt')));
});
```

File 2:

```
var rotateImage = function (angle, element) {
  var $e = $(element);
  var index = $e.data('button-index');
  var target = $('#receipt-image-'+index);
  return function () {
      angle = (angle + 90)%360;
      var className = 'rotate' + angle;
      target.removeClass().addClass(className);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a global variable so that it will be initialized as 0 once when the page loaded. Not each time on a click event as you have done.
Check this out.

```js
$(function () {
  var angle = 0;
  
  $('.rotate-receipt').on('click', function() {
    handleImage.rotateImage(this);
  });
  
  var handleImage = (function () {
  return {
    rotateImage: function (element) {
      var index = $(element).data('button-index');
      angle = (angle + 90)%360;
      console.log('Angle::'+angle);
      var className = 'rotate' + angle;
      console.log('Class Name::'+className);
      $('#receipt-image-'+index).removeClass().addClass(className);
    }
  };
}());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="rotate-receipt" data-button-index="1">Rotate</button>
<div id="receipt-image-1">Image to rotate</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i made it working myself, just `var angle = 0;` outside the funct

Comment: That solution will not work, if you are using it multiple places.